# javascript running total adding incorrectly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Hey everyone I'm trying to do a very simple calculation using javascript to find a running total.  I seem to be missing something.  I did look through SO and found some very similar scenarios but, I can't seem to relate to my own code.

Here is the script I am using to calc my running total.

```
    var total = 0;

    function GetTotal(txtBox) {
        total += parseInt(txtBox.value) || 0;
        $("#chkTotal").html(total);
    }
```

and here is some code from my view:

```
 <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBox("FirstDemo", String.Empty, new { id = "firstdemo", onchange =     "GetTotal(this)" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstDemo)
    </div>


<div>
        <h3>Total Checked</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="chkTotal"></div>
```

The total calculates perfectly, until a value is changed in a text box, in which case whatever has been entered in the textbox is added again to the running total.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You'll need to either subtract the previous value (which means you have to track it), or you'll have to iterate over all of the fields and sum them every time one of them changes (the more common approach).

Comment: You should include a `radix` parameter in your `parseInt` calls: `parseInt(txtBox.value, 10)`

Comment: based on the javascript you posted, whenever value changed in the textbox, it is added to the running total. Isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: Im really new to programming so anything you all could show me would be great, but @ElenaDBA, ideally I would like for the value of the text box to only be added to the the running total based on its current value.  Once the value in the text box has changed, I need the total to match the current value of the sum of all text boxs.

Comment: So you want to only modify the running total when textbox value has changed based on values of all textboxes and not when the user changed its value? Did I understand you correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the global scope of your `total` variable: I imagine you have several text fields in the form where you set them up to handle the `onchage` event the same way. The first time you enter something, the value is added correctly to total but the moment you change something in any of the text fields, it adds again the new value. Again, because `total` has global scope.

You should really move `total` locally inside the function and re-parse all values in the input elements you are interested in.

Since you are using jquery, you could do something like this instead:

```
function GetTotal(txtBox) {
    var total = 0;
    $('input:text').each(function(index, value) {
        total += parseInt($(value).val() || 0);
    });

    $("#chkTotal").html(total);
}​
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CF74T/) demonstrating it for you.

Comment: I tried moving the total inside of the function, but im not positive i am doing this right.  When I do the total just takes the value of the highest integer in all text boxes

Comment: @BenjaminRandal posted a complete jsfiddle sample. Check it out.

Comment: Wow this is awesome, jsfiddle is pretty neat as well.  Your solution works perfectly.  The only problem I am running into is that I have two running totals on this particular view... They seem to be conflicting with this solution, is there a way to separate the two functions (GetTotal/GetTotal2) to associate with the correct editor fields/textboxs?

Comment: All good now :) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445442/jquery-multiple-running-totals

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution, loop through all the form elements and redo the calculation.

I see jQuery in your code so it is a basic selector that gets the elements and an each loop.

```
function GetTotal(txtBox) {
    var total = 0;
    $(".calculationClass").each(
        function() {
            total += parseInt(this.value,10) || 0;
        }
    );
    $("#chkTotal").html(total);
}
```

Comment: Cool, tried this but im calculating 0 now, is ".calculationClass" something i should assign to my <div> / textbox field?

Comment: You need to change the selector so it matches the elements you want to calculate.