# jQuery multiple running totals

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

0I am using jQuery to calculate a running total on multiple textboxes.  Just found an awesome response on how to get that working a few days ago, but now I am running into another problem.  When using one selector, the total for GetTotal is calculated perfectly.  However, when I include the second selector, the totals begin to conflict with one another, and no longer calculate properly.  I have been searching for a solution to this for some time now, does anyone have any ideas?

Here is the selector i am currently using:

```
function GetTotal(txtBox) {
        var total = 0;
        $('input:text').each(function(index, value) {
            total += parseInt($(value).val() || 0);
        });

        $("#chkTotal").html(total);
    }
```

My view uses these txt boxes

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBox("Field1", String.Empty, new {InputType = "text", id = "field1", onchange = "GetTotal(this)" })

    </div>


    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBox("Field2", String.Empty, new {InputType = "text",  id = "field2", onchange = "GetTotal(this)" })

    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Total Checked</h3>
    </div>

<div id="chkTotal"></div>
```

Now I am trying to implement another selector which will total two additional editor fields...

```
function GetTotal1(txtBox) {
        var total1 = 0;
        $('input:text').each(function (index, value) {
            total1 += parseInt($(value).val() || 0);
        });

        $("#disTotal").html(total1);
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBox("Field3", String.Empty, new {InputType = "text", id = "field3", onchange = "GetTotal1(this)" })

    </div>


    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBox("Field4", String.Empty, new {InputType = "text", id = "field4", onchange = "GetTotal1(this)" })

    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Total Distributed</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="disTotal"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different HTML classes on the two sums, like

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBox("Field1", String.Empty, new {@class = "total0", InputType = "text", id = "field1", onchange = "GetTotal(this)" })
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBox("Field2", String.Empty, new {@class = "total0", InputType = "text",  id = "field2", onchange = "GetTotal(this)" })
</div>
<div>
    <h3>Total Checked</h3>
</div>
<div id="chkTotal"></div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBox("Field3", String.Empty, new {@class = "total1", InputType = "text", id = "field3", onchange = "GetTotal1(this)" })
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBox("Field4", String.Empty, new {@class = "total1", InputType = "text", id = "field4", onchange = "GetTotal1(this)" })
</div>
<div>
    <h3>Total Distributed</h3>
</div>
<div id="disTotal"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function GetTotal(txtBox) {
    var total = 0;
    $('input:text.total0').each(function(index, value) {
        total += parseInt($(value).val() || 0);
    });

    $("#chkTotal").html(total);
}

function GetTotal1(txtBox) {
    var total1 = 0;
    $('input:text.total1').each(function (index, value) {
        total1 += parseInt($(value).val() || 0);
    });

    $("#disTotal").html(total1);
}
```

Comment: You could even Combine the two JavaScript functions and make the class a parameter. I leave this as an excercise. :)

Comment: Yes sure. Also now he's passing the parameter 'this' but not using it in his functions

Comment: I noticed that after I posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your each() function runs all input fields no matter if you defined two different functions...

```
$('input:text').each(...
```

get ALL 4 input fields in both functions.

One approach is to set a class for each surrounding div ie:

```
 <div class="editor-field group1">
```

And then in your function have

```
 $('.group1 input:text').each(function( ...
```

An even more useful approach would be to use the function parameter to pass the class:

```
function GetTotal(group) {
    var total = 0;
    $('.'+group+' input:text').each(function(index, value) {
        total += parseInt($(value).val() || 0);
    });

    $("#chkTotal"+group).html(total);
}
```

You would need to rename the total divs for each group:

```
<div id="chkTotalgroup1"></div>
```

Then change "this" in your onChange handlers to each group you want to summarize. (group1, group2 and so on...)

```
onchange = "GetTotal1(group1)"
```

Comment: Yeah, I that var inside of the function so that when the user edits the text box the value will recalc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424298/javascript-running-total-adding-incorrectly